# How to plot a smooth LogLogPlot of an oscillatory function having damping

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, logarithmic-scale

I am trying to plot a damping solution with `LogLogPlot`

```
res = DSolve[{x''[t] + 0.1 x'[t] + 1  x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1,x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t]
LogLogPlot[Evaluate[x[t] /. res], {t, 0, 4000}]
```

But it is giving a wrong plot like this instead of a smooth oscillatory plot
[image]

My actual problem is like that

```
NDSolve[Rationalize[
SetPrecision[{y1'[x] + 4 y1[x]/x == 
 0, (4 y2'[x])/x + (10^-36 x^6 y2[x] + 0.5 y1'[x]* y2'[x])/y1[x] +
   y2''[x] == 0, y1[1] == 10^33, y2'[1] == 0, y2[1] == 10^8}, 
10]], {y1, y2}, {x, 10^0, 10^15}, 
Method -> {"Chasing", "ExtraPrecision" -> 10, 
"ChasingType" -> "NonlinearChasing"}, MaxSteps -> 10000000]
```

by plotting `y2` I am getting [image] a plot that is not smooth

Comment: use `Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. res], {t, 0, 100}]`

Comment: This is an example plot I need to do with `Log` scale

Comment: Negative values don't plot on Log scales very well.

Comment: What is wrong with suggestion given by @valarmorghulis?  You can also try to make your own plot range, like this `LogLogPlot[Evaluate[x[t] /. res], {t, 0, 4000}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.001, 1}}]`  But I think reducing range of `t` is better.

Comment: Try `LogLinearPlot` instead of `LogLogPlot` if you must have a log scale.

Comment: Thanks for all of your valuable comments, `Log` scale with `x-axis` is ok for me

Comment: If you use `LogLinearPlot` there is no additional  information for larger values of `t`. Recommend that you use `Manipulate` to determine the max value of `t` necessary for your purposes. `Manipulate[LogLinearPlot[Evaluate[x[t] /. res], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 150, MaxRecursion -> 10, PlotRange -> All], {{tmax, 4000}, 100, 4000, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: Are you after the envelope function? Your solution is oscillatory so you can't get rid of the zero crossings.

Comment: Zero crossings here are inevitable(oscillatory) but why are they not smooth after the first few oscillations

Comment: Why should the function smooth out after a few crossings?

Comment: by 'being not smooth' I am trying to say these are too noisy in nature rather than a smooth diminishing oscillation

Comment: @Hugh have you seen my edited 'actual problem'

Comment: Sorry I did not look at the actual function. I will look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a plotting problem as well as a problem with running out of time steps?

```
  sol = NDSolve[
   Rationalize[
    SetPrecision[{y1'[x] + 4 y1[x]/x == 
       0, (4 y2'[x])/x + (10^-36 x^6 y2[x] + 0.5 y1'[x]*y2'[x])/
         y1[x] + y2''[x] == 0, y1[1] == 10^33, y2'[1] == 0, 
      y2[1] == 10^8}, 10]], {y1, y2}, {x, 10^0, 10^15}, 
   Method -> {"Chasing", "ExtraPrecision" -> 10, 
     "ChasingType" -> "NonlinearChasing"}, MaxSteps -> 10000000];
LogLogPlot[Evaluate[y2[x] /. sol], {x, 1, 6.911505130968583`*^6}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This does look ragged at the end. However, this is due to Mathematic having a plotting algorithm which starts with a default number of points and tries to plot by refining the original number of points.  You have to tell it to use more points if you wish to catch more detail.

If we choose a short length towards the end and do a linear plot we can see that your result is still oscillatory. Also, If we plot using a Log Log plot over a larger range the amplitude seems to be almost constant.

```
{x1, x2} = (y2 /. sol)[[1, 1, 1]];
Plot[Evaluate[y2[x] /. sol], {x, x2 - 200, x2}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 1000]
LogLogPlot[Evaluate[y2[x] /. sol], {x, x2 - 2000, x2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 1000]
```

[image]

[image]

Does that help?

I have just noticed that your problem has an exact solution in terms of Bessel functions.

```
esol1 = DSolve[{y1'[x] + 4 y1[x]/x == 
    0, (4 y2'[x])/x + (10^-36 x^6 y2[x] + 0.5 y1'[x]*y2'[x])/y1[x] + 
     y2''[x] == 0, y1[1] == 10^33, y2'[1] == 0, 
   y2[1] == 10^8}, {y1[x], y2[x]}, {x, 10^0, 10^15}]

(*
{{y1[x] -> 1.*10^33/x^4., 
  y2[x] -> (1/Sqrt[
   x])(1.76344*10^-12 BesselJ[-0.0833333, 5.27046*10^-36 x^6] + 
     8.83948*10^10 BesselJ[0.0833333, 5.27046*10^-36 x^6])}}

*)
```

Does that help?